Isolating impact inherited from OpenTelemetry Collector pipelines exporter destinations issues
I was reading this article about OpenTelemetry Collector and pipeline backpressure: OpenTelemetry Collector Under the Hood: Backpressure – Axoflow
The article illustrates what happens with a pipeline configured to send log data to two separate OTLP endpoints when one of the endpoints is down.
The consequence is that the pipeline eventually stops sending data to the other healthy endpoint.
The article also explains how to mitigate the propagation of the problem to the other endpoint by using separate pipelines.
So here are my questions:

Is this a general common behavior applicable to any combination of exporters included in the same pipeline? In other words, is separation of exporter instances in different pipelines the way to achieve true isolation?
Or does it depend on exporter implementation?
Why is it behaving this way? Doesn’t each exporter component instance (otlp/1 and otlp/2) have it own queue? Is the reason perhaps due to fan-out implementation aspects (similar to what is mentioned for receivers here: Architecture | OpenTelemetry)?
Thanks in advance!
Best Regards
/Vincent
Note: I have asked the same question on the OpenTelemetry slack channel here (see link)

